# interface from app layer to access fpga driver

Tags: linux-device-driver

I am working on developing a fpga driver for a fpga customized board which is connected to the cpu board on a bus. It is not using PCI bus.

What is the best interface that can be chosen to perform read/write from the application layer ? Can the ioctl operation be used or I need to use filesystems like /procfs or /sysfs for the same.

Thanks in advance. 
P.S: I am a novice in this domain.

Aditya

Answer (score 0):

The type of interface you need depends on many factors. 
If your fpga driver wants to notify (asynchronously )some events to application procfs may not be of good help. I would recommend to go with netlink sockets interface.
If no async notification is required, you can get it done with procfs or ioctl.
Using procfs also exposes your proc entries to every user who is authorized to login in to your system. You really don't want to someone to play with your files out of curiosity. On every major Linux releasae, I see the kernel interface to proc file system getting changed. Also the unstructured procfs is being slowly replced by seq file interface.
To keep the things simple you can get it done with humble ioctl().
Thanks,
Balamurugan